# AngularJS not loading css resources

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, resources, stylesheet, angular-ui-router

In my AngularJS app with the ui-router dependency, for some reason - on Google Chrome - my `background-image`s in my stylesheet is not loading (doesn't even show up in Network tab in dev tools).

Maybe it is because I've bound the link href to my scope, and change it on the fly?

index.html:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' ngIf='stylePath' ng-href='{{stylePath}}'>
```

And in my controller I set `$scope.stylePath` to `'login.css'`.

If I open dev tools and uncheck the `background-image`, and check it again, it loads the image and shows it fine.

No problems on IE11.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without giving it too much thought, I would try to remove `ngIf` and see if that was causing the issue (then work from there).

Comment: Directives cannot contain capital letters anyway as Angular converts them to dash-lowercase. ngIf for instance should be used as ng-if

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' ngIf='stylePath' ng-href='{{stylePath}}'>
```

To:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' ng-if='stylePath' ng-href='stylePath'>
```